# MS Project VBA - Save As vs Open Dialog Picker

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a bit of VBA which I want to open a Dialog Picker to select where to save and what to call a file. Then run an xml export with that infomation.

The attached code (which is run from an MS Project Macro not Excel) does work for me when I use Set fd = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) how ever I want to use Set fd = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) to save a file. When I run the code i get "Run-Time error 91 - Object Vairable or with Block vairable not set.

Is there a better way to achieve my aim or am I making a mistake some where in this code ?

Thanks in advance.

Terran

```
Sub Export_to_XML()

    Dim pj As Project
    Dim strTemplatexml As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    Set pj = ActiveProject
    ProjectName = pj.Title

    Set fd = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    'Set fd = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    fd.Title = "Select The File To Use"
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "XML Files", "*.xml", 1
    fd.InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" & ProjectName & ".xml"
    fd.Show
    strTemplatexml = fd.SelectedItems(1)

    If (strTemplatexml = "-1") Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        End
    Else

    ExportXml = strTemplatexml

    Clear_View

    'FileSaveAs Name:="C:\Temp\Exported Project File.xml", FormatID:="MSProject.XML"
    FileSaveAs Name:=ExportXml, FormatID:="MSProject.XML"
    ' Elite_Export_XML.Show
    MsgBox Prompt:="Export to " + ExportXml + " Completed"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would [`xlApp.GetSaveAsFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) work?

Comment: Sub Export_to_XML()

    Dim pj As Project
    Dim strTemplatexml As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set pjApp = New MSProject.Application
    
    Set pj = ActiveProject
    ProjectName = pj.Title
    
    Clear_View

    'Set fd = pjApp.FileSaveAs
    pjApp.FileSaveAs FormatID:="MSProject.XML"
    'MsgBox Prompt:="Export to " + fd + " Completed"
    
End Sub